# Get the model when clicking a button on a table row

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 table binded with the simple model. I'm printing the data using Table control of SAPUI5. I'm binding the name field with the name column of the table control and on the next column I have a button. When you press this button I'd like to perform some operation on the model (read) however I can't figure out a way of getting the instance of the model in the callback function for the button.

Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jexokace/1/edit?html,js,output) to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the answer to the problem thanks to a user from SAP community.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jexokace/2/edit)

Here's the updated code for the `press` event handler that resolves the current model

```
var button = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "Button",
    press: function (e) {
        var model = this.getModel();
        var path = e.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
        var obj = model.getProperty(path);
        console.log(obj);
    }
});
```